# How do I decrypt aes128 that doesn't use a secret key but bytes

Tags: encryption

I know what he used to encrypt it but have no idea how to decrypt it. The code he used to encrypt it:

```cs
    Aes aes = new AesManaged
    {
        Key = new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 },
        IV = new byte[16],
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
    };
    ICryptoTransform crypto;
    crypto = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    return crypto.TransformFinalBlock(message, 0, message.Length); //return encrypted value
}
```

Comment: The counterpart to `CreateEncryptor()` is `CreateDecryptor()`. Btw, a static IV is insecure.

Comment: I'm surprised that the encryption runs, as the (again static & unsecure) key is of length 13 bytes (and not 16 as expected).

Comment: As posted in the previous comment the key is too short (AES allows 16, 24 or 32 bytes keys). Or there is a password-based key derivation involved that you did not post (the key can be UTF8 decoded to _Ivan Medvedev_). Note, a password (even with the right length) is generally not a secure key.